# How to split a .obj file into two other files (python, open3d)?

Tags: python, object, split, mesh, open3d

I have to split a .obj file into two others. I started with transforming the mesh into a point cloud, and managed to color the points with a "cluster" method (one color per new file to create).
I don't know how to split the file (with the two distinct clusters) into two files.
Here is my code :

```
mesho3d = open3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("Model.obj",True, True)
pcd = mesho3d.sample_points_poisson_disk(number_of_points=10000, init_factor=5)
with open3d.utility.VerbosityContextManager(
        open3d.utility.VerbosityLevel.Debug) as cm:
    labels = np.array(
        pcd.cluster_dbscan(eps=0.02, min_points=10, print_progress=True))
max_label = labels.max()
print(f"point cloud has {max_label + 1} clusters")
colors = plt.get_cmap("BrBG")(labels / (max_label if max_label > 0 else 1))
colors[labels < 0] = 0
pcd.colors = open3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors[:, :3])
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is the separation using clusters an important thing for your purpose ?
I'm not familiar with Open3D but I wonder:

- are you looking to a way to isolate connex parts of a Mesh (parts that are liked together) ?
- or you are just looking for a way to arbitrarily split a Mesh object using Open3D ?

I would have posted only a comment if I had enough privilege.